# Design that "slides out" of the left side of the browser as you make the browser bigger?

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to build a blog. I would like to create a design that essentially slides out more of the picture when you drag the browser handle to the right, and slides in to a certain point when you drag the browser handle to the left. How do you do this in css??

**EDIT:**
I'm thinking you could use a float:right, width:100%, overflow:hidden, combination or something..

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly, but I don't think this can be done in CSS, or at least not in a way that's compliant with most browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I knew I was missing something. Maybe I just wasn't explaining the question well enough.. either way.. This is what I did.

```
#header {
background('header.png') top right repeat-x
width: 100%;
}
```

Now as long as I make sure the background is repeatable, I'll be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JavaScript. Do you mean the browser handle as in the scrollbar?

This might also be a bad idea considering how much of the net is accessed today on handheld systems. Also, performance may suffer if a large image is being moved around per resizing.

Comment: I mean just resizing the browser window when I say dragging the handles.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wire an `onresize` event for the window object using javascript.

[window.onresize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize)

> An event handler for the resize event
>   on the window.